# I want to filter the value in a table but I have an error

Tags: javascript

**Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined**

I have that error and I don't now why

I'm a beginner so maybe it's a very simple thing that I don't understand

```
function price() {
    var table, tr, td, input;
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    input = document.getElementById("myInput1");
    for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
      if ( parseInt(td.textContent) > parseInt(input.value)) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
```

In fact I want to hide in a table the line where their value are bigger than the value writted by the user

That is the base HTML :

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="fa fa-search" id="myInput1" onkeyup="price()" placeholder="Prix max" title="Ecrivez un prix">
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <template id="listeDestinations">
                      <tr>
                          <td>{{pays}}</td>
                          <td>{{ville}}</td>
                          <td>{{price}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </template>
            </table>
    <script src="../javascript/accueil.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/Destinations.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thank you in adavance if you help me

Comment: you are iterating all the tr's but not all the tr's have td's inside it. So your td is undefined and you cannot call a function on it. Try to solve these kinds of problems using console.log on your own.

Comment: are you using angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Line **tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");** will retrieve all **tr** in your html page and you have **2 tr** tags

After that you do **for loop** and in the first iterator in your **for loop** you will catch the first **tr** and after that you will get all **td** inside this **tr** **tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];**

but your first **tr** doesn't have any **td** It has **th** because of that this line **td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];** will return **undefined**

Comment: Thank you very much I understand my mistake now its work